# Deleting based on compare

Tags: ms-access

I'm sorry if this has already been asked, but I have not found it already answered entirely yet - so I'm hoping someone can help provide some clarification.

I have a delete query in access that I only want to delete certain rows based on if they sum to 0

Ex:

```
Tom    -1
Jill    5
John   -3
Tom     2
Jill   -3
John    3
```

I only want to delete John's records because they sum to 0.

I have the delete where exists written -- and it is good about not deleting if none sum to 0, but if even one person sums to 0 it's trying to delete all the records. How can I get it to delete only the ones that sum to 0? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like:

```
Delete from [TableName] Where [Column1] In (
Select [Column1] From [TableName] Group By [Column1] Having Sum([Column2]) = 0 )
```

Of course, replace with your own [TableName],[Column1],[Column2]